# Rectangles don't collide correctly

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, rectangles

[image: Collison]

As you can see on the top corner it says COL: False/True. This is if the player bounds and the tiles which are solids. The rectangles for the tiles and players are checked if they intercept each-other. Looks like its working right? Well nope. Look more closely.

[image: NotWorking] [image: NotWorking]

The **BOTTOM RIGHT** corner needs to be inside the tiles for it to count.

Now let's get to the code I used now that hopefully you understand the problem.

**Player Bounds (Rectangle)**

```
playerBounds.Width = 32;
playerBounds.Height = 64;
playerBounds.X = (int)this.position.X;
playerBounds.Y = (int)this.position.Y;
```

**Tile Bounds (Rectangle)**

```
newTile.bounds = new Rectangle(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
```

Now onto how it detects it:

```
for (int x = 0; x < Tilemap.MAP_WIDTH; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Tilemap.MAP_HEIGHT; y++)
            {

                if (tm.tile[x, y].bounds.Intersects(playerBounds))
                {
                    if (tm.tile[x, y].getSolid())
                    {
                        Colliding = true;
                    } else
                    {
                        Colliding = false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

**Move**

```
    public void Move(Vector2 pos)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < speed; i++)
        {

            position += pos;
        }

    }
```

I have used breakpoints at the collision detection loop. And the rectangle fully covers the character and the tiles.

Comment: My first guess is that either A: Maths miscalculation, or B: A geometry translation error, leading to the illusion that it is colliding, when in fact the coordinates are not.

Comment: Are you rendering the quad from the top left origin? Or is it centered origin, with a -x/y vertices? This would lead to a visual illusion of collision. Essentially your bounding box is lower and more to the right than the actual quad visually exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding previous collisions in your loop. The result will always be the solid-state of the last tile that intersects with the player. Try an adaptation like this:

```
Colliding = false;
for (int x = 0; x < Tilemap.MAP_WIDTH; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < Tilemap.MAP_HEIGHT; y++)
    {
        if (tm.tile[x, y].bounds.Intersects(playerBounds) && tm.tile[x, y].getSolid())
        {
            Colliding = true;
            break;                    
        }
    }
    if(Colliding)
        break;
}
```

A more efficient approach would only check the tiles that actually intersect. Since you use simple axis-aligned rectangles, the set of intersecting tiles should not be hard to calculate.